# Oracle SELECT in SELECT statement optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Does oracle optimize select statement within a select?

for example simple query

```
SELECT
 test.a as a,
 test.b as b,
 (SELECT id from inner_table WHERE inner_table.code = 'active')
FROM test
```

lets say table test has 1000 records, what would Oracle do?

Execute select each time, for each record? Cached it?

Or there is a way to use it ones ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Oracle will cache scalar sub-queries. Tom Kyte has a [good piece on the subject.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html)

In your case, I would expect that the subquery will be exececuted once and the cached value used for subsequent rows.

Comment: Thanks, good article. Is there any way to verify that oracle cached it?

Comment: Maybe [this asktom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2683853500346598211) will help you.